# Need to see my passwords in Chrome

Tags: 16.04, google-chrome

Am using Ubuntu 16.04 with Chrome. How can I print off my passwords from the Keyring. Have gone into the keyring and it lists many entries but I need to see the passwords.

Comment: You want to print all your passwords, or you just want to see the password for a specific entry?

Answer (score 2):

Enter

```
chrome://settings/passwords
```

in the address line and click on the eye () symbols next to the accounts.